# Notation for weighted norm of polynomial in lattice reduction

Tags: summation, notation, cryptography

Where does [this definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5rs1.png) for the weighted norm of a polynomial $h(x,y)$ come from?

I do not understand the notation for the weighted norm of a polynomial because I am used to summation notation with lower and upper bounds for one variable, such as $$\sum_{n=1}^{5}$$ The notation $$\sum_{i, j}$$ confuses me because I see two variables but no upper or lower bounds.

The [weighted norm is defined here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5rs1.png), in Glenn Durfee's PhD thesis about the RSA cryptosystem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Capital-sigma_notation